# Batch Scripting Events Run on open of Any file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I know you can most likely do this much easier in programming languages such as C, VBScript, Python, JS, etc. but I want to try this specifically in batch. I want to create what would be the equivalent of an event listener in batch that executes a command whenever the user opens ANY file. As a proof of concept, just simply running echo in cmd whenever someone runs any file or a specific file such as Microsoft word.
I think I found the correct command being eventcreate, but I have no idea what the event would be called. Again, I'm sure this is much easier in other programming languages but I want to do this in using windows commands. Any help on how to do this with eventcreate or another windows command would be appreciated. How does one do this?

Here's the eventcreate according to windows documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/eventcreate

```
eventcreate [/s <computer> [/u <domain\user> [/p <password>]] {[/l {APPLICATION|SYSTEM}]|[/so <srcname>]} /t {ERROR|WARNING|INFORMATION|SUCCESSAUDIT|FAILUREAUDIT} /id <eventID> /d <description>
```

I may be completely wrong about eventcreate.

Comment: So much stuff happens in the background that your task would most likely always be running. `eventcreate` is for manually adding entries to system log files, so this isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: @SomethingDark thanks. Is there some type of event listener for user opening files in batch?

Comment: Task Scheduler can act based on new events in the event log, but I'm not aware of any generic "file was opened" event. _Maybe_ 4656 or 4663.

Comment: @SomethingDark So in theory, could I enable auditing for the opening of the particular file. And then create an action when the system audits a user accessing the file? Like would that be the way of going about it.

Comment: It might make sense to use the .Net FileSystemWatcher.  Here is an example. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b

Comment: @lit thanks. does it come with Windows automatically? And it works with batch?

Comment: @JustAFellowCoder, yes. If you are on a supported Windows system, it will have PowerShell is available. If you are running Windows/98 or Windows/XP, it is unlikely to be available.

Comment: @lit thanks ill look into it